# Android Emulator not able to access internet

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using Android studio, I have set up the emulator through the AVD and everything is working fine except the fact that the emulator can't access the internet at all.

I have set up the APN settings, I put the right proxy, port, username, and password but I doubt the `"APN NAME"` & `"SERVER"`; I wrote my company's website url as the Apn name and the server like "www.xxxxxxx.com.

Actually, the error I get is as the pic below shows:

[image]

Any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add internet permission to you manifest if not added,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I've already put this in my application manifest, the emulator browser itself can't access internet

Comment: You should probably check if your internet connection is working.

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is, you need to make sure your PC is connected t the Internet and then restart the emulator. Then it will work for you.

What you are seeing happens because you turn on the emulator before your PC has connected to the Internet.